# How to use environment variables within a command in jq script files?

Tags: json, jq, ksh

I am working with a large quantity of OpenAPI 3.0.0 files from which I need to create html pages. Each OpenAPI file represents an entity in a large object model. The Swagger Viewer, redoc-cli, and other tools do not produce the type of documentation I need. Here is an example file:

```
{
    "openapi": "3.0.0",
    "paths": {},
    "info": {
        "title": "My File",
        "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "components": {
        "schemas": {
            "my_entity_name": {
                "type": "object",
                "description": "....",
                "properties": {
                    "propertyOne": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "description": "..."
                    },
                    "propertyTwo": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "format": "date",
                        "description": "..."
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Within my solution I am using jq to parse the files (macOS, ksh). Since there are so many, I would like to pass an environment variable to jq. This is straightforward in the shell:

```
 % entity_name=my_entity_name
 % jq -r 'select(.components.schemas.'$entity_name'.properties != null)' file.json
```

In a script file the approach is similar, and I get the results I expect. However, given the nature of what I am trying to do, I'd like to use the jq -f option to put the jq commands in a file.

I've attempted putting the following in a file called `jqscript.jq`:

```
 select(.components.schemas.'$entity_name'.properties != null)
```

And I call make the call thus:

```
  % jq -rf jqscript.jq --arg entity_name "$entity_name" file.json
```

This results in an error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
select(.components.schemas.'$entity_name'.properties != null)                           
jq: 1 compile error
```

I've tried to decipher how to use an environment variable in such a situation by modifying the `'$entity_name'` to `$entity_name` (removing the single quotes),`$[entity_name]`, `${entity_name}`, et cetera but I had similar results.

I was able to verify that variables can be passed to jq script files with the following example script:

```
value: $entity_name
} |
.value
```

When I run with this file with `% jq -rf jqscript.jq --arg entity_name "$entity_name" file.json`, I get the expected value for entity_name returned.

How can I go about using an environment variable that is both within a jq command and that command is in a jq script file?

Comment: Remove the single quotes, it should simply be: `select(.components.schemas.$entity_name.properties != null)`

Comment: That gives me ```jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START ``` (I also edited the question to reflect that).

Comment: Let me try that again: `jq --arg entity_name "$entity_name" -r 'select(.components.schemas[$entity_name].properties != null)' file.json`

Comment: You're trying to combine multiple things but breaking them in different ways. Pass environment variables through arguments (there's also existing Stack Overflow questions on that) _and_ using strings to access properties should use `[]` (also has existing questions on it)

Comment: Thank you! Updating the script file to have ```select(.components.schemas[$entity_name].properties != null)``` and calling via ```jq -rf jqscript.jq --arg entity_name "$entity_name" filejson``` seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dynamically constructing a filter using the *value* of a variable. This is fragile, as the resulting expression is parsed, rather than using the value of the variable literally (similar to SQL injection attacks).

You can access the environment directly using `$ENV`.

```
 % export entity_name=my_entity_name
 % jq -r 'select(.components.schemas[$ENV.entity_name].properties != null)' file.json
```

or simply pass the key as an explicit argument

```
% jq -r --arg entity_name my_entity_name 'select(.components.schemas[$entity_name].properties != null)' file.json
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this less fragile? Or do the responses account for that?